# Media player keyboard shortcuts keep breaking

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, media-buttons

I use keyboard short.cuts to control apps that use the media controls.

But frequently after opening/closing apps that use media controls, the keyboard shortcuts stop working (even though they did previously). I can control it using the UI media controls in the notifications centre even if the keyboard shortcuts don't work, so something must be broken here.

The only thing that's been able to fix this is rebooting, which I shouldn't have to do (nor should I have to run some command to restart the media service or whatever).

### Environment

- Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
- Gnome 3.36.8

Comment: I'm also experiencing issues, tested with [evtest](https://superuser.com/a/748473/63279) and what I can see is that the media keys are now on a different input device. standard keyboard: `/dev/input/event6: Logitech HID compliant keyboard` , media keys: `/dev/input/event7: Logitech HID compliant keyboard Consumer Control` - uname -a `Linux box 5.4.0-67-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 18:03:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` - similar to your question, it worked yesterday and now it does not.

Comment: Everyone FYI I've opened an issue for this: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gsound/-/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to close the Chromium Webbrowser.

Re-opening it does not prevent the button from working then.

I previously had a shortcut configured on the key for `rhythmbox-client --play-pause` in the keyboard system settings, and removed it.

The keyboard system settings is not detecting the play/pause button any longer for keyboard shortcuts (it does not assign it anew), the button still works.

---

- Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
- uname -a `Linux box 5.4.0-67-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 18:03:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Having to frequently close the Chromium browser is annoying. I also don't want to use separate keybindings for multiple media players just because of this, that's a nuisance.

Comment: Okay lucky me then as I only needed to do this once. It is a week and some days now running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which seems to have this problem. Is it also Chromium on your end?

Comment: Yep, Brave browser which is Chromium-based.